# TF400813: The user '' is not authorized to access this resource - Azure DevOps TFVC

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli, tfvc

I have create a pipeline and trying to trigger and download the artifacts via Azure CLI (tried both windows powershell and Developer powershell).

I can log in, trigger the pipeline without any issue, but when tried the below command to download the artifact it throws the error message 'TF400813: The user '' is not authorized to access this resource'

```
az pipelines runs artifact download --org <organization> --project <Project name> --artifact-name <Pipeline name> --path <local download path> --run-id 11
```

I am using PAT to log in and the user is assigned as the administrator and assigned to the relevant project too. PAT has full access.

Further, i tried log in interactively by using *az login*, but same error occurs.

**PAT Setting**

[image: PAT Setting]

**Organization Setting**

[image: Organization Setting]

[image: Organization User Setting]

**Project Setting**

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems computer cache conflicts with the provided user, it worked when i tried with a different PC, thanks everyone for the support.

Comment: FYI, please do not use 'Publish Build Artifact' as it does not support container download via CLI, instead use 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'

Answer (score 0):

Test the scenario, everything works as expected. The following steps for your reference:

```
az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/{org}
Enter PAT
az pipelines runs artifact download --org https://dev.azure.com/{org} --project 0508-t --artifact-name TFVC --path C:\temp\1128 --run-id 90811
```

[image]

According to the error message, it seems that the affected user doesn't have the permission to access the pipeline artifacts.

Please check the pipeline/build security settings, just make sure the affected user has the correct permission to view and access the build/pipeline.

To narrow down and investigate the issue further, please try the following things and check the result.

- Try login with another user account which has the correct permission to view and access the build/pipeline, generate a new Full scope PAT and then try it again.
- If possible, please try with the owner or PCA account and check if it has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Project Administrator in the same project with the artifact to run the az command in local powershell:

```
az login --allow-no-subscription
az devops login --org https://dev.azure.com/{org name}
PAT Token: #generate by the PA with full access
az pipelines runs artifact download --org https://dev.azure.com/{org name} --project {project name} --artifact-name {artifact name} --path {path} --run-id {buildid}
```

[image]

Then go to the target directory here in my sample in 'C:\Users\Administrator' folder you could find the artifact.

For your issue, please check the following steps that may be the cause:
1.Please go to organization settings->policy and check whether the policy has been disable. If so, please enable the 'Third party application access via OAuth' and see whether the issue still happens.

2.Check whether there is proxy or firewall in your local that cause the issue.

3.Clean cache, login in from an Inprivate window then generate a new PTA for a try.

And for your reference, if you run it through Azure Pipeline, you could consider to use system PAT.

```
$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = '$(System.AccessToken)'
```

I hope it could do some help.

[image]